# getting error Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'

Tags: nativescript

i just added `tns plugin add nativescript-pager` and run the app `tns build android`

I'm sure that its because of the new updates given to plugin for ns 6 version. but i'm not getting how to solve this.

```
Duplicate class com.rd.IndicatorManager found in modules classes.jar (com.github.adrielcafe:PageIndicatorView:1.0.6) and classes.jar (com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.3)
Duplicate class com.rd.IndicatorManager$Listener found in modules classes.jar (com.github.adrielcafe:PageIndicatorView:1.0.6) and classes.jar (com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.3)
Duplicate class com.rd.PageIndicatorView found in modules classes.jar (com.github.adrielcafe:PageIndicatorView:1.0.6) and classes.jar (com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.3)
Duplicate class com.rd.PageIndicatorView$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.github.adrielcafe:PageIndicatorView:1.0.6) and classes.jar (com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.3)
Duplicate class com.rd.PageIndicatorView$2 found in modules classes.jar (com.github.adrielcafe:PageIndicatorView:1.0.6) and classes.jar (com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.3)
Duplicate class com.rd.PageIndicatorView$3 found in modules classes.jar (com.github.adrielcafe:PageIndicatorView:1.0.6) and classes.jar (com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.3)
Duplicate class com.rd.animation.AnimationManager found in modules classes.jar (com.github.adrielcafe:PageIndicatorView:1.0.6) and classes.jar (com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.3)
Duplicate class com.rd.animation.controller.AnimationController found in modules classes.jar (com.github.adrielcafe:PageIndicatorView:1.0.6) and classes.jar (com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.3)
.
.
.
.
.
Duplicate class com.rd.animation.type.FillAnimation$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.github.adrielcafe:PageIndicatorView:1.0.6) and classes.jar
(com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.3)
Duplicate class com.rd.animation.type.ScaleAnimation found in modules classes.jar (com.github.adrielcafe:PageIndicatorView:1.0.6) and classes.jar (com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.3)
Duplicate class com.rd.animation.type.ScaleAnimation$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.github.adrielcafe:PageIndicatorView:1.0.6) and classes.jar (com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.3)
Duplicate class com.rd.animation.type.ScaleDownAnimation found in modules classes.jar (com.github.adrielcafe:PageIndicatorView:1.0.6) and classes.jar (com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.3)
Duplicate class com.rd.animation.type.SlideAnimation found in modules classes.jar (com.github.adrielcafe:PageIndicatorView:1.0.6) and classes.jar (com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.3)
Duplicate class com.rd.animation.type.SlideAnimation$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.github.adrielcafe:PageIndicatorView:1.0.6) and classes.jar (com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.3)
Duplicate class com.rd.animation.type.SwapAnimation found in modules classes.jar (com.github.adrielcafe:PageIndicatorView:1.0.6) and classes.jar (com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.3)
Duplicate class com.rd.animation.type.SwapAnimation$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.github.adrielcafe:PageIndicatorView:1.0.6) and classes.jar
(com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.3)
Duplicate class com.rd.animation.type.ThinWormAnimation found in modules classes.jar (com.github.adrielcafe:PageIndicatorView:1.0.6) and classes.jar (com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.3)
Duplicate class com.rd.animation.type.ThinWormAnimation$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.github.adrielcafe:PageIndicatorView:1.0.6) and classes.jar (com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.3)
Duplicate class com.rd.animation.type.WormAnimation found in modules classes.jar (com.github.adrielcafe:PageIndicatorView:1.0.6) and classes.jar (com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.3)
Duplicate class com.rd.animation.type.WormAnimation$1 found in modules classes.jar (com.github.adrielcafe:PageIndicatorView:1.0.6) and classes.jar
(com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.3)
Duplicate class com.rd.animation.type.WormAnimation$RectValues found in modules classes.jar (com.github.adrielcafe:PageIndicatorView:1.0.6) and classes.jar (com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.3)
Duplicate class com.rd.draw.DrawManager found in modules classes.jar 
.
.
.
.
modules classes.jar (com.github.adrielcafe:PageIndicatorView:1.0.6) and classes.jar (com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.3)
Duplicate class com.rd.draw.data.PositionSavedState found in modules classes.jar .
.
.
.
Duplicate class com.rd.draw.drawer.type.ScaleDrawer found in modules classes.jar (com.github.adrielcafe:PageIndicatorView:1.0.6) and classes.jar (com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.3)
Duplicate class com.rd.draw.drawer.type.SlideDrawer found in modules classes.jar (com.github.adrielcafe:PageIndicatorView:1.0.6) and classes.jar 
.
.
.
.

Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.
```

So, i need a way to resolve this issue because those people who developed plugin haven't tested this before releasing.
i cannot even start with plugin.

***Edit :-***

I got to know one thing that, because i'm using naivescript-carousel plugin nativescript-pager was giving this error. But I need carousel to auto display stream of images. and pager for quiz screen. What shall i do now.

Comment: did you try running `tns platform clean android` before trying to build?

Comment: @ShivaPrasad i tried that and I'm getting same error.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YYn5H6tkpFopiU4uSciPCbjUOFO75ajb/view?usp=sharing
you can try this custom pack of older version of nativescript-pager that I use.

to install it, place it in your project folder and do
npm i ./nativescript-pager-10.0.0.tgz

Comment: @ShivaPrasad I just removed carousel pugin and started using new version of  pager only. and its working fine. So, You mark the comment as answer and close this thread. thank you.